# Using subprocess call return No such file or directory

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, server, subprocess

I have used this with success in the past

```
from subprocess import call
```

with

```
import os
```

To make sure I have the correct path printing I looked at the console after

```
print str(os.path.abspath(str(os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, 'user_2/SampleIllustration.pdf'))))])
```

This path/directory most certainly exists; however, after trying to convert the pdf to a text file with

```
call(["pdftotext", "-layout", str(os.path.abspath(str(os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, 'user_2/SampleIllustration.pdf'))))])
```

I receive an error that

```
No such file or directory
```

What is strange is that when I am developing on my local machine, this `call` works as expected. It's only when I'm on the server that I receive this message.

EDIT:

The complete error message is:

```
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Comment: Can you show us what is the result of building `abspath` from its arguments?

Comment: What is the complete error message?

Comment: @ThierryLathuille I edited to give the complete error message

Comment: It might not be able to find `pdftotext`. Try using absolute path instead. Probably `/usr/bin/pdftotext`

Comment: @ikac I am hesitant to give the actual results of the file path, but suffice it to say it's something like `/home/something/something/media/user_2/filename.pdf`

Comment: @HåkenLid I thought by using `os.path.abspath(...` it would return the absolute path and that does indeed seem to be the case.

Comment: The absolute path of the pdf file. I'm talking about the path to the executable `pdftotext`.

Comment: @HåkenLid `pdftotext` is a system call.

Comment: @HåkenLid ok, I didn't think of that. Let me try. I'm not entirely sure where that call is located.

Comment: Are you sure it's a system call? It's not the pdftotext that comes with [poppler-utils](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poppler_(software))

Comment: @HåkenLid Is it possible that I didn't install that?

Comment: It's the kind of thing that might come preinstalled with many linux distros.

Comment: @HåkenLid  It did on my machine, but perhaps it's not on my server.

Comment: Yes. It's probably not installed on the server unless you specifically did so. On desktop distros it's required as a dependency to the default pdf viewer. and other gui programs that can view or modify pdf files. But those things are not included in the server version.

Comment: @HåkenLid in that case, can you tell me how to install it or should I search for or create a new question?

Comment: If you are using ubuntu or debian: `sudo apt-get install poppler-utils`. It's probably named the same or something similar in other distros.

Comment: @HåkenLid so you think this would work? `sudo apt-get install xpdf`?

Comment: @HåkenLid Oh, I see: `poppler-util`. I just saw something that said `xpdf` when I did a quick search.

Comment: @HåkenLid this worked. Indeed, what I had on my local machine by default was not on the server and so needed to be installed. If you feel inclined, feel free to formalize your comments as an answer and I'd be happy to reward you with acceptance.

Comment: @HåkenLid this worked. Indeed, what I had on my local machine by default was not on the server and so needed to be installed. If you feel inclined, feel free to formalize your comments as an answer and I'd be happy to reward you with acceptance.